# Apache Kylin - Can't select partition date from date dimension

Tags: kylin

I am doing a project in Apache Kylin and I would like to use a date column from my date dimension as a partition column as I don't have any date columns in my fact table. However, as you can see in the image, it only allows me to select my fact table as partition table, I don't have a choice of selecting any dimension tables:

[image: Partition Table Selection]

Also, I want to clarify that I have connected my fact table with date dimension:

[image: dimensions]

I have read here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/5338102381/ that it should be possible to choose the date field either from the fact table or dimension table... So does anyone know why I can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Kylin (as of 3.1.3) only supports partition column from fact table.

For the example above, the options I can see are

1. Can the CREATED_DATE_ID be a partition column? Likely not, as it does not look like a date column.
2. Create a view joining F_QUESTION and D_DATE, and let the view be a new fact table to create kylin model.

At least the second option should work.